# How to optimize function that adds padding to image with NEON Intrinsics?

Tags: c, image-processing, neon

im new to NEON and whilst i can do some processing i struggle with lack of knowledge at some basics concepts especially with optimizing 2d arrays.

```
uint8_t** add_padding(uint8_t** img,int width, int height) {

    uint8_t** padded_image = (uint8_t**)calloc((height + 2), sizeof(uint8_t*));

    for (int i = 0; i < height + 2; i++) {
        if (padded_image) {
            padded_image[i] = (uint8_t*)calloc((width + 2), sizeof(uint8_t));
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < height +1 ; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < width + 1; j++) {
            padded_image[i][j] = img[i - 1][j - 1];
        }
    }


    return padded_image;
}
```

How can i vectorize function above using NEON intrinsics in C ?

Comment: try using `memcpy`

Comment: If the goal is to transfer the original image into the padded array, the bottom loop is currently clipping the last row/col. It needs to be "< height+1" and "< width+1".

Comment: Also, why waste cycles zeroing the whole memory with calloc if you are just going to overwrite the majority of it with data? (Assuming padding is trivially small compared to the size of the image).

Comment: @solidpixel yes that is correct ive edited it, image is pretty small actually (around 100x60)but that is also a fair point

Answer (score 1):

Two things pop up.

If possible, use contiguous memory allocation.

Plan how you are going to implement excess data widths (non-multiples of SIMD width). I typically use the method of overlapped SIMD registers:

```
 if (width < 16) abort();   // or handle with non-simd methods

 *output_row++ = 0;  // write the left margin
 
 // handle multiples of SIMD width -- read and write 16 bytes at a time
 while (width >= 16) {
    uint8x16_t data = vld1q_u8(input_row);
    input_row += 16;
    width -= 16;
    vst1q_u8(output_row, data);
    output_row += 16;
 }

 // handle the excess by loading the 16 last characters of the row
 if (width) {
    input_row += width;
    output_row += width;
    uint8x16_t data = vld1q_u8(input_row - 16);
    vst1q_u8(output_row - 16, data);
 }

 // handle the right margin
 *output_row++ = 0;
```

A margin of 1 at every side hints that you are going to filter the image using some 3x3 kernel, but the filtering can be done efficiently even without the explicit margin.

```
 if (width < 16) return alternative_non_simd_implementation();

 uint8x16_t previous = vdupq_n_u8(0);   // zero initial margin
 // vs uint8x16_t previous = vdupq_n_u8(*input_row); // replicated margin

 // horizontally form three vectors
 // Z|0123456789abcde        <-- previous, Z was not read from the image
 //   0123456789abcdeF       <-- current
 //    123456789abcdefG      <-- next
 while (width > 16) {
    uint8x16_t next = vdupq_n_u8(input_row[16]); // peek 1 element
    uint8x16_t current = vld1q_u8(input_row);
    previous = vextq_u8(previous, current, 15);
    next = vextq_u8(current, next, 1);
    // then compute something from the 3 vectors, write it to target
    current = vmaxq_u8(vmaxq_u8(previous, next), current);
    vst1q_u8(output_row, current);
    previous = current;  // update the context
    width -= 16;
    input_row += 16;
 }
 // then handle the excess...
 // previous = ........Z, in case width == 16
 // previous = ........F, in case width == 32
 // if width % 16 == 0, previous contains already a valid byte
 // otherwise we need to read it explicitly
 if (width & 15) {
    // revert the input pointer so that the last byte we read
    // falls in the lane 15 of the SIMD 
    input_row -= 16;
    input_row += width;
    output_row -= 16;
    output_row += width;
    // there is at least one readable data that is not margin
    // to the left of input_row, which we read
    previous = vdupq_n_u8(input_row[-1]);
 }
 
 uint8x16_t current = vld1q_u8(input_row);
 uint8x16_t next = vdupq_n_u8(0);       // right margin
 previous = vextq_u8(previous, current, 15);
 next = vextq_u8(current, next, 1);

 // again, compute something + write it
 current = vmaxq_u8(vmaxq_u8(previous, next), current);
 vst1q_u8(output_row, current);
```

That fragment only handled one row, but it can of course be extended to read from three pointers.

```
 void outer_loop(uint8_t *start_ptr, uint8_t *out_ptr, int width, int height) {
   uint8_t *zero = calloc(width);  // have a single zero row
   
   for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
      uint8_t *mid_row = start_ptr + i * width;
      uint8_t *top_row = i > 0 ? mid_row - width : zero;
      uint8_t *bot_row = i < height-1 ? mid_row + width : zero;
      
      process_three_rows(top_row, mid_row, bot_row, width, out_ptr);
      out_ptr += width;
   }
   free(zero);
 }
```